# Get current user's assigned site during registration on WordPress Multi-site

Tags: wordpress, multisite

When a user is registered on a WordPress subsite. That specific subsite will be assigned to that user and user will be treated as a member of that specific subsite.
I want to get that subsite's info. 
e.g. John is a member of site1.domain.com
and jack is a member of site2.domain.com

so what I want is that when John is logged in a function returns me site1.domain.com
and when Jack is logged in it returns me site2.domain.com.

so that I can display specific content and change URLs accordingly

Comment: WordPress only allows user registration to be done on all sites by default, not just one of the multisite domains. I found [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/), which allows you to change these settings on a site by site basis, may be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks but I found the solution I was looking for.

Comment: It's get_blogs_of_user(). which lists all sites of which user is a member